# Prove $\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}=\frac{a+ib}{1+c}$ if $b+ic=(1+a)z$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $b+ic=(1+a)z$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ then prove that $\dfrac{1+iz}{1-iz}=\dfrac{a+ib}{1+c}$

**My Attempt**
$$
z=\frac{b}{1+a}+i\frac{c}{1+a}\implies iz=\frac{-c}{1+a}+i\frac{b}{1+a}\\
\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}=\frac{\frac{1+a-c}{1+a}+i\frac{b}{1+a}}{\frac{1+a+c}{1+a}-i\frac{b}{1+a}}=\frac{1+a-c+ib}{1+a+c-ib}.\frac{1+a+c+ib}{1+a+c+ib}\\
=\frac{(1+a+ib)^2-c^2}{(1+a+c)^2+b^2}=\frac{1+a^2-b^2+2a+2iab+2ib-c^2}{1+a^2+c^2+2a+2c+2ac+b^2}
$$
I don't think its going anywhere with my attempt, how can I solve it easily as it was asked as a multiple choice question ?

Comment: How is a prove that question multiple choice?

Comment: @PeterForeman it was to evaluate $\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$, and the solution given in my reference was $\frac{a+ib}{1+c}$

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=DA6WBQAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PA202&lpg=RA1-PA202&dq=1%2Biz+a%2Bib+1%2Bc&source=bl&ots=NWEDaEljPr&sig=ACfU3U1oQ71MgQ57rPikyTvOfkA2XOMBnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBjcTRhYHgAhUMUI8KHUs_BqcQ6AEwCXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=1%2Biz%20a%2Bib%201%2Bc&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}&=\frac{(1+a+ib)^2-c^2}{(1+a+c)^2+b^2}\\
&=\frac{1+a^2-b^2-c^2+2a+2iab+2ib}{1+a^2+b^2+c^2+2a+2c+2ac}\\
&=\frac{1+a^2-(1-a^2)+2a+2iab+2ib}{1+1+2a+2c+2ac}\\
&=\frac{2a^2+2a+2iab+2ib}{2+2a+2c+2ac}\\
&=\frac{a^2+a+iab+ib}{1+a+c+ac}\\
&=\frac{a(a+1)+ib(a+1)}{(1+a)+c(1+a)}\\
&=\frac{a+ib}{1+c}\\
\end{align}

Can you find out your mistake now?

If you are interested, see [spherical representation of complex numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)